# Save breeze knockout array offline

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I'm developing an app with a worklist.

It is made up of `users` which are added by querying a database using [breeze](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/lap-knockout.html).

`User`'s can be added or removed from the worklist using the app.

I would like to be able to save the list offline, so that when the browser is refreshed the list is re-populated.

The list at the moment is a ko observable array of breeze entities.

I've tried saving it straight into offline cache but I get circular reference errors. I know I can save all the data by exporting from the entity manager; however I would like to keep track of the worklist not the whole cache.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Google breeze.js export entities

Answer (score 1):

PW Kad is correct, you can export just a subset of the entities in the cache with the *EntityManager.exportEntities* method. Something like

```
exportList = [ entity1, entity2, entity3 ];
var exported = myEntityManager.exportEntities(exportList);
```

Comment: so then when the page reloads and i import those 3 entities into the manager how would i query for those entities to populate the observable array? I would have to do a local get all or similar?

Comment: The [`EntityManager.importEntities` method](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_importEntities) returns an object containing the entities that were imported. Of course you can always query the cache if you know what to look for.

Comment: Also consider adding the second parameter to the `exportEntities` call, `includeMetadata=false`, which will reduce dramatically the size of the `exported` object.